Ckeditor disappears when there is a validation error in form on live
I am facing this issue on the live server. I have a form with the ckeditor. When I try to submit the form, if there is a validation error for any field, ckeditor disappears. On the local there is no such issue. I am using Livewire with Laravel.
I tried to produce the error on the local but faild. I also deployed the project using virtual host on nginx but still it worked on the local machine.
<form  wire:submit.prevent="saveBlog" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    @csrf
    
    <div class="row card-body">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="blogTitle">Blog Title</label>
                <input type="text" wire:change="convertUrl()" wire:model.defer="state.title" name="blogTitle"  class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" id="blogTitle">
                @error('title')
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{$message}} </div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="slug">Blog Custom URL</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model.defer="state.slug" name="slug"  class="form-control @error('slug') is-invalid @enderror" id="slug">
                @error('slug')
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{$message}} </div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="blogTitle">Meta Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="metaDescription" wire:model.defer="state.meta_description"  class="form-control @error('meta_description') is-invalid @enderror" id="metaDescription">
                @error('meta_description')
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{$message}}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="blogCategory">Category of blog post</label>
                <select id="blogCategory" wire:model.defer="state.blog_cat_id" name="blogCategory" class="form-control @error('blog_cat_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                    <option value="333" selected>Choose Blog Category</option>
                        @foreach($cats as $cat)
                        <option value="{{ $cat->id }}"> {{ $cat->name }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
                @error('blog_cat_id')
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{$message}}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="blogThumbnail">Blog Main Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" wire:model="thumbnail" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" accept="image/*">
                @if($thumbnail)
                    <img src="{{$thumbnail->temporaryUrl()}}" class="img-fluid" width="100">
                @endif
                @error('thumnbnail')
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"> {{$message}} </div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group" wire:ignore>
                <label for="blogDescription">Blog Detail Description</label>
                <textarea wire:model.defer="state.description" data-description="@this" id="blogDescription" name="blogDescription" class="form-control description"></textarea>
                <div class="text-danger" id="blogDescription_error"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addBlogBtn"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> Submit New Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- /.row -->
    
</form>

This is livewire class
class CreateBlog extends AdminComponent
{
     public $state = [];
     use WithFileUploads;
     public $thumbnail;
     public $cities;
     public function mount(){
    $this->cities = City::where('active', 1)->get();}

public function render()
{
    $cats = BlogCat::where('active', 1)->get();
    return view('livewire.admin.blogs.create-blog', ['cats' => $cats])->layout('layouts.super-admin');
}

public function saveBlog(){
    //dd($this->thumbnail)
    $data = Validator::make($this->state, [
            'title' => 'required|unique:blogs',
            'blog_cat_id' => 'required|digits_between:0,9',
            'slug' => 'required|unique:blogs',
            'meta_description' => 'required',
            'thumbnail' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,gif|max:10024',
            'description' => 'required',
    ])->validate();
    $image = $this->thumbnail;
    //$name = Storage::disk('blogs')->put('', $image);
    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $img = $img->resize(1000, null, function($constraint){
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    
    $type = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $data['slug'] = $this->url_title(strtolower($this->state['slug']));
    $name = $data['slug'].'-'.rand(10, 100).'.'.$type;
    Storage::putFileAs(
        'public/blogs', $image, $name);
    $data['thumbnail'] = $name;
    //$slug = $this->url_title(strtolower($data['title']));
    //$data['slug'] = $slug.'-'.rand(5,1000);
    $data['poster_id'] = 1;
    $data['active'] = 1;
    $data['status'] = 1;
    $data['is_commented'] = 0;
    $blog = Blog::create($data);
    if($blog){
        $thumb1 = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(400, 300, function($constraint){
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->encode('webp', 100);
        $thumb2 = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(400, 300, function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->encode('jpg', 100);
        $name = $this->generateRandomString().time().'.'.'webp';
        $name2 = $this->generateRandomString().time().'.'.'jpg';
        
        Storage::put('public/thumbnail/blog-thumbs/'.$name, $thumb1);
        Storage::put('public/thumbnail/blog-thumbs/'.$name2, $thumb2);
    
        $thumb = new BlogThumb();
        $thumb->blog_id = $blog->id;
        $thumb->name = $name;
        $thumb->jpg_name = $name2;
        $thumb->save();
    }
    if($data['blog_cat_id'] == 7){
        FrontEndController::newsSitemap();
    }else{
        FrontEndController::sitemap();
    }
    
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('hide-form', ['message' => 'Blog post added successfully!']);
    return redirect('super-admin/blogs');
}
public function convertUrl(){
    $this->state['slug'] = $this->url_title(strtolower($this->state['title']));
}
public function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

//Make Slug
public function url_title($str, $separator = '-', $lowercase = FALSE)
{
    if ($separator == 'dash') 
    {
        $separator = '-';
    }
    else if ($separator == 'underscore')
    {
        $separator = '_';
    }
    
    $q_separator = preg_quote($separator);

    $trans = array(
        '&.+?;'                 => '',
        '[^a-z0-9 _-]'          => '',
        '\s+'                   => $separator,
        '('.$q_separator.')+'   => $separator
    );

    $str = strip_tags($str);

    foreach ($trans as $key => $val)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("#".$key."#i", $val, $str);
    }

    if ($lowercase === TRUE)
    {
        $str = strtolower($str);
    }

    return trim($str, $separator);
}

}
This is ckeditor javascript
<script>
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#blogDescription'), {
    heading: {
      options: [{
          model: 'paragraph',
          title: 'Paragraph',
          class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'
        },
        {
          model: 'heading1',
          view: 'h2',
          title: 'Heading 2',
          class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
        },
        {
          model: 'heading3',
          view: 'h3',
          title: 'Heading 3',
          class: 'ck-heading_heading3'
        },
        {
          model: 'heading4',
          view: 'h4',
          title: 'Heading 4',
          class: 'ck-heading_heading4'
        },

      ]
    },
    // plugins: [SourceEditing],
    // toolbar: ['sourceEditing'],
  })
  .then(editor => {
    // Your code when the editor is ready
    document.querySelector('#addBlogBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      let description = $('#blogDescription').data('description');
      eval(description).set('state.description', editor.getData());
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });


The code appears to be written for Livewire 2, is this your version? You should also post the class and javascript code for Ckeditor

Yes Livewire 2.5

Do you see any error in the browser console?

There is no error in console. I am facing this problem only on live website. On local it works fine.

I solved this problem by re-initializing the ckeditor in the script.
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        function initCKEditor() {
            const editorElement = document.querySelector('#blogDescription');
            if (editorElement) {
                if (window.editor) {
                    window.editor.destroy().catch(error => console.error('Error destroying CKEditor:', error));
                }

                ClassicEditor
                    .create(editorElement, {
                        heading: {
                            options: [
                                { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                                { model: 'heading1', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                                { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
                                { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Heading 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                            ]
                        }
                    })
                    .then(editor => {
                        window.editor = editor;

                        // Synchronize CKEditor content with Livewire
                        document.querySelector('#addBlogBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
                            let description = $('#blogDescription').data('description');
                            eval(description).set('state.description', editor.getData());
                        });

                        // Sync CKEditor data to textarea before form submission
                        document.getElementById('blogForm').addEventListener('submit', function() {
                            document.getElementById('blogDescription').value = editor.getData();
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error initializing CKEditor:', error));
            }
        }

        // Initialize CKEditor on page load
        initCKEditor();

        // Reinitialize CKEditor on Livewire updates
        Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
            initCKEditor();
        });
    });
</script>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
